# Is this how I would rewrite code so that it fits into a class?

Tags: python, class, methods

If I had a class like this:

```
class WorldView:
   def __init__(self, view_cols, view_rows, screen, world, tile_width,
      tile_height, mouse_img=None):
      self.viewport = pygame.Rect(0, 0, view_cols, view_rows)
      self.screen = screen
      self.mouse_pt = point.Point(0, 0)
      self.world = world
      self.tile_width = tile_width
      self.tile_height = tile_height
      self.num_rows = world.num_rows
      self.num_cols = world.num_cols
      self.mouse_img = mouse_img
```

And a few functions like these (left out of the class):

```
def clamp(v, low, high):
   return min(high, max(v, low))


def create_shifted_viewport(viewport, delta, num_rows, num_cols):
   new_x = clamp(viewport.left + delta[0], 0, num_cols - viewport.width)
   new_y = clamp(viewport.top + delta[1], 0, num_rows - viewport.height)

   return pygame.Rect(new_x, new_y, viewport.width, viewport.height)


def draw_background(view):
   for y in range(0, view.viewport.height):
      for x in range(0, view.viewport.width):
         w_pt = viewport_to_world(view.viewport, point.Point(x, y))
         img = worldmodel.get_background_image(view.world, w_pt)
         view.screen.blit(img, (x * view.tile_width, y * view.tile_height))
```

And I wanted to rewrite these functions so that they are methods of the class WorldView (although they don't HAVE to be if the function seems more appropriate to leave out of the class), would it look it something like this?

```
class WorldView:
   def __init__(self, view_cols, view_rows, screen, world, tile_width,
      tile_height, mouse_img=None):
      self.viewport = pygame.Rect(0, 0, view_cols, view_rows)
      self.screen = screen
      self.mouse_pt = point.Point(0, 0)
      self.world = world
      self.tile_width = tile_width
      self.tile_height = tile_height
      self.num_rows = world.num_rows
      self.num_cols = world.num_cols
      self.mouse_img = mouse_img

   def create_shifted_viewport(self, viewport, delta):
      new_x = clamp(viewport.left + delta[0], 0, self.num_cols - viewport.width)
      new_y = clamp(viewport.top + delta[1], 0, self.num_rows - viewport.height)

      return pygame.Rect(new_x, new_y, viewport.width, viewport.height)

   def draw_background(self, view):
      for y in range(0, view.viewport.height):
         for x in range(0, view.viewport.width):
            w_pt = viewport_to_world(view.viewport, point.Point(x, y))
            img = worldmodel.get_background_image(view.world, w_pt)
            view.screen.blit(img, (x * view.tile_width, y * view.tile_height))
```

I'm still a little unsure about whether or not I should include "clamp" as a method; I can see that "create_shifted_viewport" uses clamp to get "new_x and new_y", but should I include clamp as a method? Or should I just leave it out of the class? Generally speaking, when a method in a class is using another function that's currently left out of the class, is it logical to include that function as a method?

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes. I hopes fixed those, see the comments.

```
class WorldView:
   def __init__(self, view_cols, view_rows, screen, world, tile_width,
      tile_height, mouse_img=None):
      self.viewport = pygame.Rect(0, 0, view_cols, view_rows)
      self.screen = screen
      self.mouse_pt = point.Point(0, 0)
      self.world = world
      self.tile_width = tile_width
      self.tile_height = tile_height
      # these seems not required since you can get these from self.world
      #self.num_rows = world.num_rows
      #self.num_cols = world.num_cols

      self.mouse_img = mouse_img

   def clamp(self, v, low, high):
       return min(high, max(v, low))

   def create_shifted_viewport(self, delta):
      #need self.num_cols, no need viewport parameter
      new_x = self.clamp(self.viewport.left + delta[0], 0, self.world.num_cols - viewport.width)
      new_y = self.clamp(self.viewport.top + delta[1], 0, self.world.num_rows - viewport.height)
      #need self.viewport
      return pygame.Rect(new_x, new_y, self.viewport.width, self.viewport.height)


   def draw_background(self):
      # i hope view.viewport is the self.viewport
      for y in range(0, self.viewport.height):
         for x in range(0, self.viewport.width):
            w_pt = viewport_to_world(self.viewport, point.Point(x, y))
            img = worldmodel.get_background_image(self.world, w_pt)
            self.screen.blit(img, (x * self.tile_width, y * self.tile_height))
```

Comment: Thanks! So generally, when a method uses another function that's left outside of the class, we want to include that function in the class right?

Comment: @Karen that depends upon the problem. if your clamp function is only needed for this class. it seems also ok if you taken out of class if it is used by other function too.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. So in this case, why did we choose to include the function "clamp" inside the class??

Comment: @Karen it seem like this function is only used by this class. can i know what is the param `view` in `def draw_background(self,view)`. it seems it is self.viewport is ok??

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out what the code does exactly, but I believe that "view" will help draw a basic grid. What if there's another function that's not in the class that uses the method, "create_shifted_viewport"? Would that mean that I'd also have to move the function using that method into the class? Thanks!

Comment: i hope `view` and `self.viewport` are the same. am i right??

Comment: Hmm..I have a feeling they may be different, because if you look at the functions, viewport and view both appear as arguments. So I'm guessing they mean different things. :(